# Comparison of two tables from two different servers

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the differences between two tables in two different servers. How should I go about successfully completing this task?

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT 
    'TABLE1-ONLY' AS SRC, T1.*       
FROM
    (      
       :connect SPXPBDB      
       SELECT *       
       FROM FINLS.FIN.DBO.EMPID        
       EXCEPT     
       :Connect SPXFINDB     
       SELECT *     
       FROM FIN.DBO.EMPIDFIN     
   ) AS T1      
UNION ALL      
SELECT 
    'TABLE2-ONLY' AS SRC, T2.*     
FROM
    (     
       :Connect SPXFINDB       
       SELECT *      
       FROM FIN.DBO.EMPIDFIN     
       EXCEPT      
       :connect SPXPBDB      
       SELECT *
       FROM FINLS.FIN.DBO.EMPID       
    ) AS T2;
```

Comment: That doesn't look like Microsoft SQL Server code. Have you tagged your question with the correct platform?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the SRC field to do something outside the 2 selects, for example `group by` on them or use a `where` statement:

```
SELECT 
  A,B,C, SUM(COUNTER) AS COUNTER
FROM
(
SELECT 
    'TABLE1-ONLY' AS SRC, T1.*, 1 AS COUNTER    
FROM
    (      
       ***  
   ) AS T1      
UNION ALL      
SELECT 
    'TABLE2-ONLY' AS SRC, T2.*, 1 AS COUNTER
FROM
    (     
      ****       
    ) AS T2
)
GROUP BY A,B,C <-- Fields from T1
```

Now you can find if the record is in both tables/databases